# Missing links in Create 2 documentation

Tags: irobot-create

The latest edition of Servo Magazine clued me to the existence of the Create2.

So one is now on the way and I've begun downloading the documentation. The problem is that the doc's which are dated 2014 are full of referrals to other documents but those links are broken or non-existent.

iRobot appears to continue supporting STEM and Create2, so how does one find the missing files?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Robotics:SE. Can you edit your question to include more detail about the missing documents and where you are trying to download them from.

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* David Funk, but I'm afraid that questions which can only be answered by the pre-sales or technical support team for a specific manufacturer or supplier aren't a good fit for a stack exchange site. *[Practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)* are always welcome here though, so if you edit your question to fit our community guidelines we can reopen it for you. Please take a look at [ask] and [about] for more information on how stack exchange works.

Comment: Try [contacting their customer support](https://homesupport.irobot.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/200) and ask them to provide/fix the documentation you're looking for. If it's not on their website it may not exist.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a question for iRobot customer support.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're looking for. If I go to the [Create2 page](https://www.irobot.com/about-irobot/stem/create-2.aspx), there is a button that says, "[Get Started](https://www.irobot.com/about-irobot/stem/create-2/projects.aspx)" that takes me to a page that gives the [Open Interface Specification](https://www.irobotweb.com/-/media/MainSite/Files/About/STEM/Create/2018-07-19_iRobot_Roomba_600_Open_Interface_Spec.pdf), dated July 19, 2018.

If you click the link for "[More...](https://www.irobot.com/about-irobot/stem/create-2/projects.aspx#link)" under the **Create 2 Projects** heading, it takes you to a list of other projects, including [Arduino](https://www.irobotweb.com/-/media/MainSite/PDFs/About/STEM/Create/Arduino_Tutorial.pdf) and [RaspberryPi](https://www.irobotweb.com/-/media/MainSite/PDFs/About/STEM/Create/RaspberryPi_Tutorial.pdf) tutorials, a [battery power tutorial](https://www.irobotweb.com/-/media/MainSite/PDFs/About/STEM/Create/BatteryPower.pdf), as well as [cable pinout](https://www.irobotweb.com/-/media/MainSite/Files/About/STEM/Create/Create2-CablePinOut.pdf) diagram, [chassis screw location](https://www.irobotweb.com/-/media/MainSite/PDFs/About/STEM/Create/iRobotCreate2-ScrewBossLocations.pdf) diagram, and a host of other documents pertaining to different communication protocols.

Comment: I went to Create2 page, I went to Getting Started, I clicked Create 2 Deco Cover Modification.  the pdf opens, it has an embedded link "deco cover template" which is broken.  This document is not the only one that that has this issue.

Comment: I see someone else is also having problems finding the "deco cover template" file.

Comment: Long story short, this link was broken accidentally while updating other content. Another user suggested using the WaybackMachine to find it; that works, but access to the document has been restored at on the main irobot.com site. Please note that I am an iRobot employee, but the postings on this site are my own and don't necessarily represent iRobot's positions, strategies, or opinions.